# XRDP same user multiple session

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, xrdp

I'm trying to make XRDP work with multiple sessions on my linux mint server.
Right now, i can connect only if there are no other session running on the system (I had to disable autologin).

I don't know why, but with the Raspberry it just works by default the way I want: when I connect to XRDP, a new session is created for every client. When another client connects to the same server with the same user, a new session is created.

I tried to change the `Policy` setting in the `/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini` file from `Default`  to `UBDC` but nothing changed.

It's the first question I post, so I ask you to be really patient with me and ask me the files you may need to understand the situation.

I swear I searched all the internet but found nothing that helped. I just know it can be done 'cause my Raspberry does it for some odd reason.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Does XRDP in your server run with '--nodaemon' option?
If so you will restart xrdp without '--nodaemon' option, then XRDP works well as you want.

My server (CentOS 8) has the same problem and I was troubled.

I try to run xrdp without '--nodaemon' option, then I could connect with multiple sessions.
So run xrdp deamon without '--nodaemon' at Linux startup.

CentOS8 sample

```
$ sudo sed -i "s/ --nodaemon//" /usr/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service

$ sudo dnf systemctl restart xrdp
```

ref but japanese : [XRDPの1ユーザマルチセッションの有効化](http://funatsukiba.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/04/30/212057)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to do that but didn't work: "--nodaemon" was already missing from the init file. But thanks for the time spent, really appreciated.